# T-SQL : filter out all employees who left before > 6 months

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a new employee-database that filters out all employees, who left the company longer than 6 months ago from today.

I have a table with entry date, exit date and tried something like :

```
 WHERE [exit date] > = DATEADD(M, -6, getdate())
```

That didn't work because it shows only the employees who left the company longer than 6 months ago. I just want to filter them out automatically and only show the employees, who are still employed er left the company lesser than 6 months ago.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: where exitdate is null or exitdate<=dateadd(m,-6,getdate())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to check for null:**

```sql
WHERE ([exit date] IS NULL OR [exit date] > = DATEADD(M, -6, getdate()))
```

**Do *not* try tricks with `NOT` and `<`**

```sql
WHERE NOT ([exit date] < DATEADD(M, -6, getdate()))
```

This doesn't work because `NULL` rows will just result in `UNKNOWN`, so those rows will not be returned.

---

You *can* do this though, you may find it performs faster or slower than the first version:

```sql
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
   WHERE [exit date] < DATEADD(M, -6, getdate())
```

This works because if `exit date` is null then no row gets returned from the subquery.